# Why is my loop seeming to start at an index of 1?

Tags: java, arrays

```
public static void main(String args[])
{

    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    int n = scan.nextInt();
    String[] label = new String[n];
    int[] data = new int[n];
    int x = 0;

    for(x = 0; x < n*2; x++)
    {
        if (x<n)
        {
            label[x] = scan.nextLine();
        }
        if (x >= n)
        {
            data[x-n] = scan.nextInt();
        }
    }   
    System.out.print(data[0]);
}
```

When I try to input this, for example:

4
one
two
three
four

I get an error at "four." Shouldn't it be putting these string values into the array?

Comment: `'I get an error at "four."'` -- what error? Please show the entire error message.

Comment: "Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException  at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:909)  at java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1530)  at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2160)  at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2119)  at BarChart.main(BarChart.java:23)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The problem is that `nextInt` doesn't consume the line - just the integer. So you're *actually* getting labels of "", "one", "two" and "three" - and then it's trying to read the "four" as the first data element (with `nextInt`).

If you type your input like this:

```
4 one
two
three
four
1 2 3 4
```

then you'll end up with a label array of `{"one", "two", "three", "four"}` and a data array of `{1, 2, 3, 4}`.